# how to change default public schema on the psql command line

Tags: postgresql

In order to load a MS Access mdb file into PostgreSQL, I type the following command on the psql command line.

```
mdb-schema xxx.mdb postgres | psql -h xxx -U xxx -W -d xxx
```

However, the Postgres tables are made under the default public schema. I want to have them under a different schema ("network"), rather than the default schema("public"). Could you please tell me how to change from "public" to "network" in this situation?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You'll have to `SET search_path = myschema;` or `SET SCHEMA myschema;` at the top of your script. I don't think there is a way to specify it on the commandline. You could set it from the dotfiles, or use a shellscript cat construct to concatenate the two,

Comment: Yep. You could `ALTER DATABASE xxx SET search_path = myschema;` then reset it after the upload; that should do it, but will interfere with anyone else using the DB.

Comment: ... and similar for `ALTER ROLE mdb_importer SET search_path = myschema, pg_catalog;`

Comment: @CraigRinger: could you please explain how to reset the PSQL command terminal after the upload?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set PGOPTIONS:

```
mdb-schema xxx.mdb postgres | PGOPTIONS='-c search_path=network' psql -h xxx -U xxx -W -d xxx
```

and here is the proof (set schema to test_schema):

```
$ PGOPTIONS='-c search_path=test_schema' psql postgres -c 'show search_path'
 search_path 
-------------
 test_schema
(1 row)
```

Using `PGOPTIONS` you can set (almost) any configuration directive